# Add events to iCal from cocoa app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is it possible to add events to iCal from my cocoa app? I tried using CalCalendarEvent but it didn't add anything to my calendar.

```
CalCalendarStore *calStore = [CalCalendarStore defaultCalendarStore];
CalEvent *event = [CalEvent event];

CalRecurrenceRule *recRule = [[CalRecurrenceRule alloc] initYearlyRecurrenceWithInterval:1 end:[CalRecurrenceEnd recurrenceEndWithOccurrenceCount:5]];
[event setRecurrenceRule:recRule];
[event setStartDate:currentDate];
[event setEndDate:endDate];
event.isAllDay = YES;

[calStore saveEvent:event span:CalSpanThisEvent error:NULL];
```

Thanks.

Comment: Whenever something appears to be doing nothing, the first thing you should do is fix any suppressed error returns (i.e., `error:NULL`) and then check the errors (http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH204-SW1). Better than even odds `saveEvent:span:error:` is trying to tell you what you did wrong, but you've duct-taped its mouth shut. Better yet, don't ever suppress error returns in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are missing a `CalCalendar` object.
A minimal `CalEvent` looks like:

CalEvent* event = [CalEvent event];
 event.calendar = calendar; //this is important - otherwise the event does not appear in iCal
 event.title = title;
 event.startDate = startDate;
 event.endDate = endDate;

You could also check `saveEvent`'s NSError.
**Update:**  As Mike Abdullah points out in his comment, NSError should be [handled with care](http://rentzsch.tumblr.com/post/260201639/nserror-is-hard).

Comment: As ever, **don't** check the error object first. Check if the method returned `NO` and *then* look at the error object.